# How to sort property -value pair in alphabetical order with Matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to add a property-value pair to existing file. In the mean time all the properties should be ordered in alphabetical order. For example :

```
[Info] % property 1
value 1 
[system] % property 2
value 2
```

How can i add additional property such that all properties will be sorted in alphabetical order. I was able to add property -value pair to the end of the file using 
`fh = fopen(filename,'a')` but i am not able to sort them alphabetically.

so far i tried this as follows but with this one it keeps printing only the new property-value pair . I want to print remaining properties  onces it prints the new one.

```
function [] = myfun(filename ,propName,propvalue)
rfh = fopen(filename,'r');
tname = tempname();
wfh = fopen(tname,'w');
line = fgetl(rfh);

while ischar(line)

    if (line(1) == '[') && (line(end) == ']')
        property = lower(line(2:end-1)) % from ini file
        String2 = property;
        String1 = propName;
        [sat] = sor(String1,String2)% subfunction
        if sat == -1
            fprintf(wfh,'[%s]\r\n%s\r\n',propName,propvalue);
        else
            fprintf(wfh,'%s\r\n',line);
        end
    else
        fprintf(wfh,'%s\r\n',line);
    end
    line = fgetl(rfh);
end
fclose(rfh);
fclose(wfh);
movefile(tname,filename,'f')

function [sat] = sor(String1,String2)
Index = 1;

while Index < length(String1) && Index < length(String2) && String1(Index) == String2(Index)
    Index = Index + 1;
end

% Return the appropriate code
if String1(Index) < String2(Index)
    sat= -1
elseif String1(Index) > String2(Index)
    sat= +1
else % the characters at this position are equal -- the shorter of the two strings should be "less than"
    if length(String1) == length(String2)
        sat = 0
    elseif length(String1) <  length(String2)
        sat = -1
    else
        sat = +1
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about read the file into a `struct`?

```
function fileData = readFileIntoStruct( fileName )
%
% read [property] value pairs file into struct
% 
fh = fopen( fileName, 'r' ); % read handle
line = fgetl( fh );
while ischar( line )
    % property
    tkn = regexp( line, '\[([^\]+)]\]', 'once', 'tokens' );
    % read next line for value
    val = fgetl( fh );
    fileDate.(tkn{1}) = val;
    line = fgetl( fh ); % keep reading
end
fclose( fh ); % don't forget to close the file at the end.
```

Now you have all the data as a `struct` with properties as `fieldnames` and values as the `field` value.

Now you can update a property simply by:

```
function fileData = updateProperty( fileData, propName, newVal )
if isfield( fileData, propName )
    fileData.(propName) = newVal;
else
    warning( 'property %s does not exist - please add it first', propName );
end
```

You can add a property:

```
function fileData = addProperty( fileData, propName, newVal )
if ~isfield( fileData, propName )
    fileData.(propName) = newVal;
else
    warning ( 'property %s already exists, use update to change its value', propName );
end
```

You can sort the properties alphabetically using [`orderfields`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/orderfields.html):

```
fileData = orderfields( fileData );
```

You can write the `struct` back to file simply using:

```
function writeDataToFile( newFileName, fileData )
fopen( newFileName , 'w' ); %write handle
propNames = fieldnames( fileData );
for ii = 1:numel( propNames )
    fprintf( fh, '[%s]\r\n%s\r\n', propNames{ii}, fileData.(propNames{ii}) );
end
fclose( fh );
```

**Assumptions:**

1. The properties' names are legitimate Matlab field names (see variable naming for details).
2. The value of each property is always a string.
3. I did not include any error-checking code in these examples (files not found, wrongly formatted strings, etc.)
4. I assume the input file is strictly "[prop] val" pairs without any additional comments etc.

Comment: @ shai , thanks for your detail answers . However, the input file is [prop] and value in new line .

Comment: @bstar - indeed. if you look closely at `function readFileIntoStruct` `val` is taken from the **next** line (`fgetl`) in the file. Moreover, the function that writes back to file also puts them into different lines.

Comment: @ shai, thanks alot with the code it works as i need so far . On top of that i want to add /or to have stuctures properties . could give me some hint . especially to finally wirte the strucutre of properties to the file. my properties will be like : [properties] newline  key= value(this could be more than 2 key-value pair)

Comment: @ shai, thank you very much . Now every thing works perfectly . Inluding the property stru. However, i was trying to add one functionality in it . The intention is to specifiy the Data type of the property_name . like [system]%string and when i tried to write to the ini file i got an error as invalid fild name . Data type is an input by it self. Is there any way to write  the data type. Thanks

Comment: @bstar - this is a new question. please post it as such - with a link to this one.

Answer (score 3):

Is this a `.ini` file? You might want to take a look at [INIConfig](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24992-ini-config) from the MATLAB File Exchange, a set of routines for handling INI files arranged in a convenient class. I haven't used it, but perhaps it might do what you need.

If not, you can always:

1. Read in the file
2. Loop through it line by line
3. When you find a line starting with `[` followed by a word alphabetically later than the property you'd like to insert, insert your property and value
4. Include the remainder of the file
5. Write the whole file back out again.

Comment: @ Sam , Thanks for your fast reaction. could you give me some hint for step (4) on how to define the remainder. And sure the file is '.ini' file.

Comment: Read the file into a variable `filetext`. Create an empty string `temptext`. Loop through each line of `filetext`. If it does not start with `[`, or if it starts with `[` followed by a word alphabetically before your new property, add the line to `temptext`. If it starts with `[` followed by a word alphabetically after your new property, then add your new property to `temptext` and continue adding all remaining lines of `filetext` to `temptext`. Finally write out `temptext` to a new file.

Comment: @ Sam, could you give me a hint on how to continue adding the rest of the file once it added the new prop-value pair . i have been trying it but so far i did succeeded with it. u coul could have a look on my trial code above. thank you very much for your help .

Comment: Sorry @bstar, I didn't get a chance to look at this recently. In the meantime it looks like Shai has provided a very complete solution.

Comment: @ Sam. Thank you very much for your reactions . Indeed, code from shai was great . Thank you guys!!