# Property_value + matlab

Tags: matlab

For an `.ini` file with `property_value` pair, I'd like to define the datatype for `property_name` such that  I will convert the datatype based on the input argument data type .

For this reason I have been trying to read the specificed datatype from the ini file in struct format. However I am getting the error : `invalid fieldname`. How can I define `property_name` and datatype such that I'll be able to read it, and also be able to write to the ini file if i'd like to add `property_datatype_vlaue` pair?

```
[system] % string
value
[application] % string
value
```

I also need tot be able to set this datatype from my input argument.

[How to sort property -value pair in alphabetical order with Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14429468/how-to-sort-property-value-pair-in-alphabetical-order-with-matlab/14433758#comment20213224_14433758)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying the `struct` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14429468/how-to-sort-property-value-pair-in-alphabetical-order-with-matlab) to contain value and type

```
function fileData = readFileIntoStruct( fileName )
%
% read [property] value pairs file into struct
% 
fh = fopen( fileName, 'r' ); % read handle
line = fgetl( fh );
while ischar( line )
    % property
    tkn = regexp( line, '\[([^\]+)]\]\s*%\s*([^%]+)\s*$', 'once', 'tokens' );
    % read next line for value
    val = fgetl( fh );
    fileDate.(tkn{1}).val = val;
    fileDate.(tkn{1}).type = tkn{2};
    line = fgetl( fh ); % keep reading
end
fclose( fh ); % don't forget to close the file at the end.
```

**Assumptions:**

1. The properties' names are legitimate Matlab field names (see variable naming for details).
2. The value of each property is always a string.
3. I did not include any error-checking code in these examples (files not found, wrongly formatted strings, etc.)
4. I assume the input file is strictly "[prop] val" pairs without any additional comments etc.